# "login" is not defined by Pylance (web scraping)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

`login_xpath` has no error but in my last line of code `login` has an error.

`next` was written the same way so I don't understand why `next` doesn't have an error but `login` does.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
def account_info():
    with open('account_info.txt', 'r') as f:
        info = f.read().split()
        email = info[0]
        password = [1]
        return email, password
email, password = account_info()
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start.maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
email_xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/label/div/div[2]/div/input'
next_xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'
password_xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div[2]/div/input'
login_xpath = '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_xpath).send_keys(email)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_xpath).click(next)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_xpath).send_keys(password)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_xpath).click(login)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In selenium .click() doesn't require you to pass anything. That's probably the issue. Maybe it worked in the first instance as the actual text in the Twitter login flow is "Next" for the next button, but is "Log in" with a space in between for the login button. Just try this change:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_xpath).send_keys(email)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_xpath).click(next)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_xpath).send_keys(password)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_xpath).click(login)
```

To

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_xpath).send_keys(email)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_xpath).click()
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_xpath).send_keys(password)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_xpath).click()
```

Let me know if that solves the issue.