# Testing Selenium to log in to my Twitter: It does not let you inspect the element

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, twitter, webdriver

a question to anyone who can help:

Just for testing purposes, I'm trying to use Selenium4 and chrome Webdriver with Python to log in to my own Twitter. It seems Twitter has changed its interface: as soon as it detects a chrome being opened by selenium; instead of the usual login page ("https://twitter.com/login"), it opens: https://twitter.com/i/flow/login

On this page, I tried to manually inspect the element of the username field, it fails nonetheless; I tried to manually enter the username to get to the password field which is only activated once you enter the correct user name and click. The problem is that, as soon as you right-click on the password field to inspect the element, the above URL link automatically redirects itself to the username (previous page) field and won't let you inspect the password element. Anyone else is facing the same issue? Any solution? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["login" is not defined by Pylance (web scraping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571964/login-is-not-defined-by-pylance-web-scraping)

Comment: Thanks, the link you posted is relevant but Twitter keeps changing the format of the login page after every 10 trials! I found a way to enter and click the username, it shows the 'next' button that I have to click to take me to the 'password' page, but when I successfully click on the 'next' button, it suddenly changes the format of the page, then it takes me to another login page! I have this issue just on Twitter.

Comment: Why don't you use an API?

Comment: @BeChillerToo I am just trying to test my code with Selenium to see if I can log in and post a tweet on my own account; not doing any serious work. I will use API if I'm doing continuous automated work on this. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: It's possible what you said, that Twitter doesn't want you to use automation software.

Can you try entering the username, and then instead of simulating a mouse click, simulate a TAB `.send_keys(u'\ue004')` and ENTER `.send_keys(u'\ue007')`?

---

**Original answer:**

Another way to inspect an element is to:

-- Press F12

-- Click on the arrow icon

[image]

-- Click on an element on the page.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm on Linux so F12 does something else. For me the shortcut is ctrl + shift + I; I knew the arrow icon before. The thing is that the page reverts back to the previous page and doesn't give me the chance to click on the password field or use the shortcut to inspect the element; weird! Maybe it is a way that Twitter is forcing people to use their own API rather than selenium? just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to bypass the login page altogether and use Twitter's APIs to authenticate your script. This approach may be more reliable and efficient in the long run.

If not the above solution, you can also try using a different browser or a headless browser like PhantomJS, as they may have different behavior and may be able to access the password field

Comment: Thanks for suggesting PhantomJS; I didn't know about it. Maybe a good time to learn this also.